# My defered result is not being passed correctly

Tags: jquery, ajax, deferred

The returned data from the ajax call seems to be empty.  When I uncomment out the `success: function(result)` block, the results output to the console correctly, so I know the data exists. However, when I call `request().done` the deferred value appears empty.

```
function request(cat)
{    
    return $.ajax
    ({
     url: 'query.php',
     type: 'POST',
     data: {Category: cat},
     dataType: 'json'//, 
     //success: function(result) 
     //{  
     //  if(result) 
     //  {        
     //  console.log(result[0]); Result outputs to the console correctly
     //  }
     //}  
}); // end ajax call   
}

request().done(function(data) { console.log(data[0]); });  //array appears to be empty
```

Answer (score 0):

```
your code
if(result) 
{        
  console.log(result.[0]);
}
```

should be replaced as following

```
if(result) 
{        
  console.log(result[0]);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not my problem.  The period was a typo and should never have been there.  My problem is the deferred value is showing up empty whereas the commented block was displaying correctly.  The question does actually state this.